# How do I move a photo from the GIMP to Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-office, gimp, file-format

I am new to Gimp2. I am using the photo editing which I am manipulating correctly, changing the background etc. Then I save the final picture to "My Pictures" folder but the problem is I can't move the picture to another editing program e.g Microsoft Picture Management and when I am uploading the picture it goes complete with the Gimp2 logo etc.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new file in GIMP and save it, GIMP uses its native (`.xcf`) file format. This format is similar to the Adobe Photoshop (`.psd`) format in that it preserves all the layers in your image yet is not compatible with most other software.

You need to use File → Export (in GIMP 2.6 and older, use File → Save A Copy instead) to make a copy of the image in a different file format. Type in the desired file name followed by `.jpg` (for photos) or `.png` (for drawings). Some older programs may require you to save the image as a `.bmp` file instead, which takes up more disk space yet may be more compatible.

This tells GIMP which format you want to save the image in. Alternatively, you can look for these formats (and many others) in the drop-down menu.

GIMP may ask you to "Merge Visible Layers" when you save your file. This is because the `.jpg`, `.png`, and `.bmp` formats do not preserve the layers in your image.